# Installing R Visual Studio 2019

Tags: r, data-science

When I modify Visual Studio 2019 using the installer for the 'Data science and analytical applications'
It says the following

Data science and analytical applications 
Languages and tooling for creating data science applications, including Python and F#.

R is not listed. Doing some googling on that it appears not as straightforward as I had assume. Anyone have a short list of what I need to install R for Visual studio (not VS Code)